# Generalized Skorokhod spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, fa.functional-analysis

Skorokhod spaces of [càdlàg functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) are an extremely useful setting to describe stochastic processes. I'd like to understand the Skorokhod topology from a pure topological point of view, without resorting to metrizability.

Normally, one considers a metric space $M$, a closed time interval $T \subseteq \mathbb R$, and the space of càdlàg functions $D(T,M)$. This space is equipped with the Skorokhod topology, which allows one to wiggle space and time a bit.

In the end, we are concerned with have probability distributions on $D(T,M)$ rather than metric structures, which means the whole point of the topology is to just construct a nice Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

**Assumptions:** Let $T$ be a first-countable topological space equipped with a continuous partial order, and let $M$ be a first-countable topological space. Define the space of càdlàg functions $D(T,M)$ in the natural way.

**Question:** Under these relaxed assumptions, is there a natural topology on $D(T,M)$?  That is, a topology which coincides with the usual Skorokhod topology in the setting of $T \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $M$ metrizable.

Comment: Here is a good survey on Skorokhod space and generalizations: http://kpbc.umk.pl/Content/39953/kievtopologies.pdf